# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't render (Browserify and Watchify in background)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, browserify, watchify

I'm attempting to establish a basic Angular app with a module, controller, and view. I'm struggling to get angular to interpret the content within "{{}}".

I'm running Browserify which is pushing everything to "./js/bundle.js".

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="showNames">
<head>
    <script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
    <title> Help </title>
</head>

 <body>
    <h1>Show Those Names</h1>
      <ul ng-controller="namesController as namesCtrl">        
        <li ng-repeat="name in namesCtrl">{{name.names}}</li>  
      </ul>     
 </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('showNames', []);

app.controller('namesController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.names = ["jeff", "jim", "jay", "Please show up"];
 }]);
```

My browser only renders {{name.names}}.

Any idea what's going on here, what I'm missing, or how I can improve my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you referenced AngularJS ?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: a few details still missing about your setup. we're not seeing, for example, where you require() the angular. take a look at this sample project https://github.com/sombriks/blogpost-upload-angular-browserify-fngfileupload and on that package.json https://github.com/sombriks/blogpost-etdefense/blob/master/package.json so you can figure how to do a minimal setup to get thngs working.

Comment: I am referencing angular via require in the app.js, and it is being pushed to bundle.js. My biggest issue was mixing the 'controller as' and '$scope' syntaxes, and then not fully understanding how to implement ng-repeat (i.e. ng-repeat iterates over what I've assigned to $scope, not the entire controller). The app is working now and things are much clearer for me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your ng-repeat you are trying to get names form controller, you should use your model which is part of your controller ie: "name in names" not "name in namesCtrl".

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('showNames', []);

app.controller('namesController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.names = ["jeff", "jim", "jay", "Please show up"];
 }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="showNames">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title> Help </title>
</head>

 <body>
    <h1>Show Those Names</h1>
      <ul ng-controller="namesController as namesCtrl">        
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>  
      </ul>     
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used this to fix my code, except I got rid of the 'controller as' syntax entirely to keep from confusing myself while using $scope (i.e. ng-controller="namesController"). I also replaced the script tag to bring in my bundle and angular locally. This was really helpful to understand how ng-repeat works with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way to work with ng-repeat.

`<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{ name }}</li>`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply! I had a bit of confusion about the ng-repeat's iteration and syntax. I have to remember that we assign "name" as an alias to reference the $scope property we want to iterate over. So if I had something like ... $scope.person = [{name: "Bud", age: "21"}, {name: "Spock", age: "162"}] ... in my HTML  I'd write... <li ng-repeat="person in person">name:{{person.name}} + age: {{person.age}} </li> Things are much clearer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess.

1. Your controller is referenced as `namesCtrl` in your template yet you assign `names` to `$scope`. Pick one approach and stick to it
2. You're repeating over `namesCtrl`?
3. Your array entries are strings only, they have no `name` property

---

Use `$scope`...

```
<ul ng-controller="namesController">        
    <li ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">{{name}}</li>  
</ul>
```

---

or use *"controller as"*

```
app.controller('namesController', function() {
    this.names = ["jeff", "jim", "jay", "Please show up"];
});
```

and

```
<ul ng-controller="namesController as namesCtrl">        
    <li ng-repeat="name in namesCtrl.names track by $index">{{name}}</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I watched too many tutorials which took different approaches, and I confused the 'controller as' and $scope syntax. AdditYou cleared this up for me awesomely.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I watched too many tutorials which took different approaches, and I confused the 'controller as' and $scope syntax. Additionally, inside the ng-repeat I confused myself by thinking the iteration would be over everything inside the controller instead of just the xxxxx in "$scope.xxxxx". You cleared this up for me awesomely!

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code. There are multiple mistakes. try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="showNames">
<head>
<script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
<title> Help </title>
</head>

<body>
 <div ng-controller="namesController as namesCtrl">
  <h1>Show Those Names</h1>
    <ul>        
      <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>  
    </ul> 
 </div>    
</body>

</html>
```

Your app.js is okay. I am hoping it is being pushed into bundle.js